# TokenMismatchException в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, laravel

У меня стоят запросы к сайту через Routes (web.php)
Когда я просто перехожу, всё работает, но когда запускаю запрос через JavaScript
Пишет эту ошибку в консоль:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68
```

Вот мой routes (web.php) на сам запрос:

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/users'], function () {
    Route::post('/getInfo', 'Users@getInfo');
    Route::post('/newUsers', 'Users@newUsers');
    Route::post('/getStats', 'ApiController@getStats');
});
```

Вот мои запросы:

```
function getInfo() {
    requestify.post('http://' + config.domain + '/api/users/getInfo')
    .then(function(response) {
        response = JSON.parse(response.body);
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        var secondsElapsed = 0;
        var infoInt = setInterval(function () {
            response.secondsElapsed = secondsElapsed;
            io.sockets.emit('slider', response);
            secondsElapsed++;
        }, 1000);
        setTimeout(function() {
            newUsers();
            clearInterval(sliderInterval);
        }, 20000);
    }, function(response) {
        log(JSON.stringify(response.body));
    });
}

function newUsers() {
    requestify.post('http://' + config.domain + '/api/users/newUsers')
    .then(function(response) {
        response = JSON.parse(response.body);
        io.sockets.emit('newUsers', response);
    }, function(response) {
        log(JSON.stringify(response.body));
    });
}

var rotate_time = 0;
var rotate_now = 0;
var rotate = 0;

requestify.post('http://' + config.domain + '/api/users/getStats')
.then(function(res) {
    res = JSON.parse(res.body);
        log('[USERS] Число пользоватлей' + res.users.id + '('+res.users.status+')');
       log(JSON.stringify(res));
}, function(res) {
    log(JSON.stringify(res.body));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В переданных через POST данных отсутствует csrf-token.  Читай о нём тут:
http://laravel.su/docs/5.4/csrf

Comment: Да нет. Это у меня есть. В layout.blade. Это не то

Comment: Походу разобрался